# SSIS duplicate data Insert Update approach

Tags: insert, ssis, duplicates

New to SSIS. 
I have data from a set of flat files. It is possible to have the same person on the same flat file or different flat files with person different information. I process them all at the same time. 
But I need to know either to insert the record or update it (if the same person). I'm using a lookup to determine if the person exist on the table. I have already set the Old DB Destination FastLoadMaxInsertCommitSize to 1 and using Ole DB Command for updates.
But still it cant determine an update if the same person is encountered.

I also tried merge on control flow but failed.

What could  be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After Insert/Update, look for duplicate data and delete IDs(if using identity keys) lower than the max(ID).